# socket_recvfrom returns "more than response"

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I wrote a UDP Server in C++ and I am currently trying to send data from PHP to the server and receive the response. Everything works fine for the first time, but then the php buffer adds some characters to it (e.g. response is just '1', it echos '1to' or '1gg'. I've checked that the server sends a correct response.

Here is the code in PHP:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_connect($socket, '192.168.178.27', 8000);

socket_send($socket, $data, strLen($data), 0);

$from = "";
$port = 0;

socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 2048, 0, $from, $port);
socket_close($socket);

return $buf;
```

In the file that calls the function:

```
echo UDP::SendRecv("actor ". $actor->internal_name . " ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of bytes received is returned by the  `socket_recvfrom()` function itself.

Form the [documentation to `socket_recvfrom()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> **socket_recvfrom()** returns the number of bytes received, or **FALSE** if there was an error.

So do only use as much bytes from `$buf` as indictaed by `socket_recvfrom()` return value, if not `FALSE`.